# How to understand F_p as subfield of F with characteristic p?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

My book is the GTM$173$, Field and Galois Theory written by Patrick Morandi.

F$_p$ represents $Z/pZ$ ($Z$ is the integer set) in my textbook. And $F$ is a field with characteristic $p$. The author writes that 'we can view F$_p$ as subfield of $F$'. But he doesn't explain clearly what's the embedding is. I think one way is to map $1+pZ$ in $Z/pZ$ to $e$, the identity in $F$.

Also, in the picture I upload, he defines a mapping and claim $a^p=a$ iff $a\in$ F$_p$. I don't know why. Can we prove that if $a^p=a$ then $a$ must be one of the element from {$0,e,2e,3e...(p-1)e$}???

[image]

Comment: Unclear if you mean $e$ to be the additive or multiplicative identity of $F$.  Also, how are you defining characteristic of a field?  (I ask because the working definition I've used is "the number of times you can successively add the multiplicative identity before you obtain the additive identity", which makes the image of $F_p$ in $F$ exactly the one you mention.)

Comment: I refer the multiplicative identity, often denoted as $1$ or $e$
. Additive identity is usually denoted by $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, the *prime field* of any field is the subfield generated by the multiplicative identity, $1$ of the field. 
   Note that it can only be $\Bbb Q$ or $\Bbb F_p=\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$.
2. The order of any group element divides the order of the group. Apply this to the multiplicative group of $\Bbb F_p$ to see $a^{p-1}=1$ for all nonzero $a\in\Bbb F_p$, and thus $a^p=a$ follows. 
   Conversely, the polynomial $X^p-X$ can have at most $p$ roots, since we work with a field, but each element of $\Bbb F_p$ is already a root, so can't have more.